# restrict browsing to websites using FQDN only - No IP in Browsers

Tags: filter, ip

I'm trying to prevent users from typing IP addresses in their browsers as we want all outbound requests to go via our DNS servers.

Our DNS Servers have excellent filters and can block access to a whole bunch of crap on the web, we restrict all DNS queries outbound from our servers only so the only way to bypass our filters is to type in the IP address directly, is their a way to block this without a proxy, could we do it on a Linux router ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know how this feature works, in the hopes of finding a free firewall feature that could filter on it. At the packet level, a web page request (a "GET" request) for any asset (incl. e.g. images) includes the HTTP referer header field, which is the full URL from the browser address bar. I verified this using a network packet sniffer (Wireshark), and saw that when accessing a site via its IP address, the HTTP referer was "http:// num.num.num.num" (sample) whereas via its FQDN the HTTP referer was "http:// mydomainname". Filtering at the packet level could thus be used to not allow any GET requests with a referer field that starts with an IP address.